# Grooveshark code

Tags: grooveshark

Does anyone know what Grooveshark.com is coded in? I mean PHP, rails, flash........?

Comment: Edit: I take that back, it appears to not rely on Flash anymore. My apologies.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Grooveshark developer here. Grooveshark's backend is PHP 5.6, and the front end is a mixture of a ton of Javascript and a small flash shim that handles playback, https communications and a few other one-off things that were just easier to make work in flash than javascript.

This post might be helpful:
[The Tech Behind the New Grooveshark](http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2010/12/the-tech-behind-the-new-grooveshark/)

Comment: .thx for replyin...nothing better than the "horse's mouth"... ;)

Comment: tht post is the cherry on the cake.... ;)

Comment: @Jay hey I found out something you might be interested in.. how can I contact you

Comment: @Rafael.IT you can contact me at jay at grooveshark dot com

Answer (score 1):

By digging through the source it looks like PHP (PHP/5.2.14) and a *TON* of Javascript.

Comment: hmmm...but then that contradicts the first answer.......

Answer (score 0):

[Per WikiPedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grooveshark)

> Grooveshark is a rich Internet
>   application that was first written in
>   ActionScript using the Adobe Flex
>   framework that ran in Adobe Flash. In
>   December 2010, Grooveshark introduced
>   a redesign of the site that features
>   an interface rewritten to use HTML5,
>   which makes the interface perform
>   faster.